# Could not find iPhone 6 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image]enter image description hereWhat I did was, I removed the XCode version 11 on my MAC machine then re-installed version 10.3.
When I run the react-native run-ios and it no longer works. ***Could not find iPhone 6 simulator***

I have followed the solution on the StackOverFlow, replaced the code as below.

```
if (!version.includes('iOS') && !version.includes('tvOS')) {
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that may have happened. The iPhone 6 simulator may no longer be on your hard drive and/or the React tools are unable to locate the simulator.

You can download additional simulators by selecting the Components tab of the XCode preferences window and download the ones you need. [Adding Simulators](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deva7379ae35)

You can get a list of install simulators using this command:

`xcrun simctl list devices`

You can also inform the react-native tool to use a different simulator by using the `--simulator` flag, like this:

`react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"`

Hopefully one or more of these steps will help you out!

Comment: Z.Ragan - I suppose the simulators are there. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you try to use another simulator that is listed? For example: `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"`

Comment: I did. Still no luck, just wondering I have to remove all and resintall?

Comment: That is unfortunate. I wish I knew of a solution to your problem. Reinstalling might work. I hope so!

Comment: Z.Ragan - That will be last resort. Really

Comment: I am getting the same result on an older RN project built with Expo. My newer project (created this week) does not have this issue.